# tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

on installing tensorflow from here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is a compatibility problem.

Tensorflow does not have windows wheel for Python > 3.6, make sure you are running the right version.

[image: Tensorflow Windows Wheels]
You can find links here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3